# MYSQL - Max(Date) gives me right Date but wrong Value

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am querying a specific measurement based of the last date inserted using MAX

The last occurency is this one:

```
Measurement Date_insert
9.039999961 2021-03-30 11:57:2
```

When I try to query it like this:

```
SELECT m.measurement, MAX(m.date_insert) FROM measurements m
```

I get:

```
Measurement Date_insert
0.000000000 2021-03-30 11:57:2
```

> The date keeps the same which shows me that I queried the right date
> but how is it possible that the measurement changes value?

Any help would be grateful!

Comment: `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` will help you avoid invalid GROUP BY queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning `0.000000000` as measurement from the first (any) row and `MAX(m.date_insert)` is returning max value from `date_insert` column.

It's possible that `0.000000000` and `2021-03-30 11:57:2` even do not exist in same row.

Please avoid this query if your intention is to get the max `date_insert` along with the value of `measurement` column from same row. Instead use just `order by` clause with `Limit 1` as suggested by @juergen d.

But if there are multiple `measurement` value for a single `date_insert` then you can use group by clause to find the `max(measurement)` for the highest `date_inert` value. Here goes the example:

Schema:

```
create table measurements( Measurement float, Date_insert datetime);
insert into measurements values(0.000001000 ,'2021-03-30 11:57:5');
insert into measurements values(9.039999961 ,'2021-03-30 11:57:5');
insert into measurements values(0.000000000 ,'2021-03-30 11:57:2');
```

Set sql_mode:

```
 set sql_mode=only_full_group_by;
```

Query:

```
 SELECT m.date_insert, max(m.measurement)measurement
 FROM measurements m 
 group by m.date_insert
 order by m.date_insert desc
 limit 1
```

| date_insert | measurement |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-30 11:57:05 | 9.04 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1654616d87623c87eae09f8a43a59daf)*

Comment: I don't think the OP wants the max(measurement)

Comment: Op didn't ask for it. But if there is a possibility to have such data then OP should aware of it. @juergen d answered the question and I have asked OP to use that.

Answer (score 4):

You should do that

```
SELECT m.measurement, m.date_insert 
FROM measurements m 
order by m.date_insert desc
limit 1
```

Your query does not return the correct results because you mix "normal" column selects with aggregation. MySQL supports that sadly. It returns strange results. Other DB engines throw an error for your query.

Comment: Yes I could do it like this. But the thing is that I want to use it on other queries with multiple rows but I want to understand why the value changes and doesnt give me the right one

Comment: The value changes because you tell MySQL: give me the max `date_insert` and any record value of `measurement`